# Can an Imacros be created for this scenario or not?

Tags: automation, imacros

I have a CSV file of emails that I would like to have each email uploaded individually but automatically to a site.

Steps are to copy the email, go to the site and paste email in proper field. Do the same things with the first name, then confirm. Then click back to main page to input next email and name.

Is this possible with iMacros or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Use this http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference

and you can use this: http://wiki.imacros.net/!DATASOURCE